# why vue v-for doesn't rerender child component when data change?

Tags: vue.js

parent

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {ChildComponent},
  data: function() {
    return {
      itemList: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      callApi().then(res => { this.itemList= res; })
    }
  }
};

<template>
      <ol>
        <template v-for="(item) in itemList">
          <li :key="item.id">
            <child-component :item="item"></card>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ol>
</template>
```

child

```
export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
    item: { type: Object }
  },
  data: function() {
    const {
      name,
      address,
      .......
    } = this.item;
    return {
      name,
      address,
      ......
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

child get the item props which is an object.

I'm confused why the itemList point to another array, but the child doesn't update?

is it because key doesnt change? (but other data changed..)

thanks

Comment: I don't see your child-component renders anything? Did you post the whole component's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of this part of your code:

```
const {
  name,
  address,
} = this.item;
return {
  name,
  address,
};
```

What it does it copies `name` and `address` from item and return them.
It happens only once in your code while component is created.
If after that your prop `item` change, your data doesn't copy it and still returns the first values.

Solution:
If you don't change `name` or `address` in a child component, just use a prop

`this.item.name` in a script or `{{ item.name }}` in a template

It is already reactive so your component will update when prop changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `data` function is called only once on the creation of the component.

The recommended way to get data that depend on other data is to use `computed`.

```js
export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
    item: { type: Object }
  },
  computed: {
    name() {
      return this.item.name;
    },
    address() {
      return this.item.address;
    }
  }
};
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example

Comment: Prop is already reactive, there is no need for creating `computed`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you do in your child component but this is enough to do and should react to your parent component changes. Basically the idea is to use the prop. I made some tweaks also.

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {ChildComponent},
  data: function() {
    return {
      itemList: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      callApi().then(res => { this.itemList= res; })
    }
  }
};

<template>
      <ol>
        <li v-for="(item) of itemList" :key="item.id">
          <card :item="item"></card>
        </li>
      </ol>
</template>


export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
    item: { 
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ item.name }} {{ item.address }}
  </di>
</template>
```